# Variable value not being rendered in the view from controller angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am learning angular.. I tried to run a small example,but wasn't able to render correct output.Can anybody help?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AngularJS Tutorial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
        <body ng-app='app' ng-controller='MainController as main'>
    <div class='container'>
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
        <div ng-controller='SubController as sub'>
            <h2>{{sub.title}}</h2>
            <p>If we were not using the <strong>ControllerAs</strong> syntax we would have a problem using title twice!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller("MainController", function($scope){
    $scope.title = 'AngularJS Nested Controller Example';
});

angular.module('app').controller("SubController", function(){
    this.title = 'Sub-heading';
});
```

I am not able to figure out why angular variables are getting displayed as normal text instead of its assigned value. kindly help...

Comment: Everything seems to be correct. For me it works properly. The only issue that I see is the tag `body` closed twice

Comment: and the wandering app.js

Comment: what do you see in the console log?

Comment: I am getting below error :Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: It worked by adding <script src="app.js"></script>  but I did not get the logic behind it.

Comment: if you have your javascript code in a separate app.js file, which you definitely should, your html file has no way to know about it without that script tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a link to your app.js file.

Just a tip when referencing your .js files, make sure you reference any javascript which uses Angular AFTER the line where you reference angular.js

So your references should look something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script> <!-- this is the one you are missing -->
```

Comment: I added this and it worked, but I have seen in some examples that they did not add this in html file.

Comment: If that is the case, they probably included the javascript code somewhere in the html file itself. Which is technically something you can do but is not recommended for anything other than simple situations because it will be hard to keep track of as your project gets bigger. The more you learn about angular, the more you will see that this is pretty much a best practice. You will even see that people have single javascript files for each controller, filter, and service as a way to keep things organized. In my own personal web app I probably have over a dozen reference lines because of this.

Comment: Chris,I was referring http://www.revillweb.com/tutorials/angularjs-in-30-minutes-angularjs-tutorial/ tutorial for basic knowledge and they have not added the controllers name in html file.Can you please explain why?

Comment: I looked through the tutorial you linked, and it seems that the author is being inconsistent throughout the first several steps. In the setup he has the correct links to his app.js and a main.ctrl.js files. But in the next few screenshots he seems to have removed them for no apparent reason, and they show up again a few steps later. I don't really understand what you are asking though. There's only so much I can say about the tutorial in 500 chars but it seems like it's trying to cover a lot of concepts in a short space, which is not super friendly to beginners. I woud try finding another one.

Comment: I guess I was unable to explain my question. the html file in the tutorial above  doesn't have <script src="app.js"></script> line. Why is that?                             I couldn't find better tutorial tan this.Could please suggest if any?

Answer (score 0):

Please, [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/gi0juDDxM7382p4lio2w?p=preview)
It works

```
 <h1>{{main.title }}</h1>
    <div ng-controller='SubController as sub'>
        <h2>{{sub.title}}</h2>
        <p>If we were not using the <strong>ControllerAs</strong> syntax we would have a problem using title twice!</p>
    </div>
```